# Does GRUB boot other drive OS slower? [other drive: where it is not installed]

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I have dual booted my laptop. I have two SSDs one is M2 and other is SATA. GRUB bootloader is installed on the SATA SSD when I chose the OS installed on SATA it boots fast as compared to the one installed on M2 NVME. Is it normal?

Comment: Folks here are skittish about 'opinion-based' issues. Would you mind, please, specifying which OS is on the SATA drive, and which is on the M.2 NVMe drive? What's the time measured to boot the OS from SATA, and how many seconds does it take to boot from the M.2 NVMe drive? Some motherboards run M.2 drives slower when they share PCIe lanes with SATA drives (e.g., Gigabyte Z390). Which laptop model do you have, which M.2 slot is the NVMe drive in, and which SATA ports are used?